# SELECT depending on value from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, nodes, edges

I am using [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), connected to a MySQL database. There are two tables:

```
Nodes 

**id | label**
----------------
   1 | a 
   2 | b
   3 | c
   4 | d

Edges 

**source | target**
----------------
       4 | 3
       1 | 2
       2 | 3
       3 | 1
       2 | 1
       2 | 4
```

Values for `source` and `target` (Edges table) should correspond to `id` (Nodes table). I want *one* query to:

1. Select from Nodes table where `label` is `b`.
2. `id` of `b` is `2`, so select these values from Edges table where `source` is `2`.
3. Now `target` value is `3, 1, 4` where `source` is `2`, so select these values from Nodes table where `id` is `3, 1, 4`.

I tried this query, but it's not giving correct results:

```
SELECT id, label FROM nodes WHERE id IN(
   SELECT target FROM edges WHERE target In(
     SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE label = 'b'
   )
)
```

Result should look like this:

```
**id | label**
---------------- 
   2 | b
   3 | c
   1 | a
   4 | d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the join the nodes table twice with edges table like this:

```
SELECT distinct n2.*
FROM nodes n1
JOIN edges e on n1.id = e.source
JOIN nodes n2 on n2.id in (e.source, e.target)
WHERE n1.label = 'b'
```

**Demo** @ ***[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7e824/2)***

Comment: its working fine. but a little problem is there, that it is repeating row with label "2", please check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7e824/1

Comment: Just put a distinct in there

Comment: is working fine in http://sqlfiddle.com/ but in my local database this query returns zero results

Answer (score 0):

First get all the targets related to those sources where label is 'b';  then select the related labels in Nodes.

Edited: regarding you expect labels for both source and target of the Edge:

```
SELECT * FROM Nodes
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT source FROM Edges
    JOIN Nodes ON Edges.source = Nodes.id
    WHERE Nodes.label = 'b'
)
OR 
id IN (
    SELECT target FROM Edges
    JOIN Nodes ON Edges.source = Nodes.id
    WHERE Nodes.label = 'b'
)
```

Test it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b745e/3).

*Note: there's a better approach in terms of performance. I post it in another answer.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133799/discussion-between-marcm-and-shujaat).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
SELECT nodes_tmp.*
FROM nodes
JOIN edges ON nodes.id = edges.source
JOIN nodes AS nodes_tmp ON (nodes_tmp.id = edges.source OR nodes_tmp.id = edges.target)
WHERE nodes.label = 'b'
```

Test in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b745e/7)

Comment: this code is working file. but one problem is still there, that in my database it is retrieving/showing row with label 'b'  many times. Row with label 'b' after each other row.?

Comment: Check your code and compare it with current answer. Or add to your question a SQL fiddle where the problem is shown.